# How to download a file from server using angular?

Tags: angular, http

```
    this.repositoryApiService.export(repoType, repoItem, type)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.commonService.downloadFileFromServer(data.serverPath, data.name);
      }, error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

 downloadFileFromServer(serverUrl: string, fileName: string) {
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.setAttribute("style", "display: none");
        a.href = serverUrl;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        a.remove(); // remove the element
    }
```

**the data which i am getting from Server consists of url**

- doc file gets downloaded, but for pdf it gets opened up within the browser itself

Comment: could be a browser thing, maybe [this](https://superuser.com/questions/408243/prevent-chrome-from-automatically-opening-downloaded-pdf-and-image-files) can help

Comment: No, this doesn't work for me!